# Huawie deep links open in webview not in the app

Tags: android, deep-linking, huawei-mobile-services

I'm trying to make our app support the Huawei AppGAllery services like map, notification, and deep links, everything is okay except the deep link.

the links open in the Huawei browser instead of the app itself
I've added intent-filter with flag `android:autoVerify="true"`:

after my search I discovered the following:

- if I open the app setting and force manually allow for the link it's working but, it's ugly to ask the user to allow that
- after disabling the default browser and installing chrome on my Huawei device everything became working and a popup asking whether I need to open on the web or app started to appear.

**Notes:**

- I've already added the `assetlinks.json` file on my server
- the deep link working correctly on the normal android devices ( not Huawei )

after running the command `adb shell dumpsys package d` I'm getting that my app status is **ask** even after I added the `android:autoVerify="true"`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try to run :

`adb shell dumpsys package d` or `adb shell pm get-app-links PACKAGE_NAME` command to check whether the AppLinks link of an app passes the verification.

[image]

For more details, kindly refer to [this docs](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations).

Comment: I've tried that and working perfectly but still failing on Huawie

Comment: hi@Moustafa EL-Saghier, If you do not use the keyword `android:autoVerify="true"`, is the Huawei browser deeplink normal on your Huawei device?

Comment: Would you mind post the screen displayed after you run the `adb shell dumpsys package d` command? it should be like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUsx4.png).

Comment: added and my app status is ask can you see question again after edit?

Comment: yes, `always`: indicates that the app is the default app of the link. Even if two apps have the same authorized host, the dialog box for selecting an app is not displayed, indicating that the verification is successful.
`ask`: If two application hosts and paths pass the verification, a dialog box is displayed for user to select, indicating that the verification fails. So as shown in the figure, if Status is `ask`, the verification fails. Therefore, AppLinks does not take effect.

Comment: so, what do you recommend for me to do? I've added the assetlinks.json file with my package name & sha-256 of .jks file app signed with so, I don't know what is going wrong with me

Comment: As I know, re-installation triggers re-verification. This AppLinks cannot ensure that 100% verification is passed because network verification is involved.

Comment: Do you mean verification is done once the app is installed? 

what you recommend me to do now I re-installed and still same

Comment: Could it be that you are using a different signing key for the AppGallery build?

In that case, you would need to update the assetlinks.json to reflect the new SHA-256. Otherwise, the verification will fail.
I have previously seen that this can be overlooked.